# How can I get matplotlib to show full subplots in an animation?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ffmpeg, simulation

I'm trying to write a simple immune system simulator. I'm modeling infected tissue as a simple grid of cells and various intracellular signals, and I'd like to animate movement of cells in one plot and the intensity of viral presence in another as the infection progresses. I'm doing so with the `matshow` function provided by `matplotlib`. However, when I plot the two next to each other, the full grid gets clipped unless I stretch out the window myself. I can't address the problem at all when saving to an mp4.

Here's the default view, which is identical to what I observe when saving to mp4:
[image]

And here's what it looks like after stretching out the viewer window
[image]

I'm running Python 2.7.9 with matplotlib 1.4.2 on OS X 10.10.2, using ffmpeg 2.5.2 (installed via Homebrew). Below is the code I'm using to generate the animation. I tried using `plt.tight_layout()` but it didn't affect the problem. If anyone has any advice as to how to solve this, I'd really appreciate it! I'd especially like to be able to save it without viewing with `plt.show()`. Thanks!

```
def animate(self, fname=None, frames=100):
    fig, (agent_ax, signal_ax) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)

    agent_ax.set_ylim(0, self.grid.shape[0])
    agent_ax.set_xlim(0, self.grid.shape[1])
    signal_ax.set_ylim(0, self.grid.shape[0])
    signal_ax.set_xlim(0, self.grid.shape[1])

    agent_mat = agent_ax.matshow(self.display_grid(),
                                 vmin=0, vmax=10)
    signal_mat = signal_ax.matshow(self.signal_display(virus),
                                   vmin=0, vmax=20)
    fig.colorbar(signal_mat)

    def anim_update(tick):
        self.update()
        self.diffuse()
        agent_mat.set_data(self.display_grid())
        signal_mat.set_data(self.signal_display(virus))
        return agent_mat, signal_mat

    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, anim_update, frames=frames,
                                   interval=3000, blit=False)

    if fname:
        anim.save(fname, fps=5, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
    else:
        plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the matplotlib documentation

> Because of how matshow() tries to set the figure aspect ratio to be the one of the array, if you provide the number of an already existing figure, strange things may happen.

I think you're better off using `imshow` instead (which I believe is what `matshow` calls. That has an `aspect` keyword argument which you could use if it doesn't work automatically.

Also according to the matplotlib documentation,

> Sets origin to ‘upper’, ‘interpolation’ to ‘nearest’ and ‘aspect’ to equal.

I think you want to do the first two, but leave `aspect` as auto.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one simple solution would be to just specify the width of the figure when creating it:

```
fig, (agent_ax, signal_ax) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True, 
        figsize=(16,6))
```